# Java watch folder and action when all files and folders in watch folder have finished downloading

Tags: java, watch

I am trying to write the facility to process media files using a watch folder.  The Oracle example [WatchDir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) demonstrates how to know when there are changes in a folder.  However the issue with this is that I don't know when all the media has finished uploading.  So for example when an SD card containing media which contains multiple files in different folders is dragged onto the watch folder, I need to be able process the media once all the files and sub folders are present.  Media is not always just stored in single files but may have sidecar files so both sets of files need to be present in order to process the files correctly.  Can anyone suggest how I can know that all files and sub folders have finished being copied into the watch folder?

This is my slightly modified version of the WatchDir to include logging:

```
public class WatchDir {

    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
    private final boolean recursive;
    private boolean trace = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     */
    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        if (trace) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (prev == null) {
                System.out.format("register: %s%n", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                    System.out.format("update: %s -> %s%n", prev, dir);
                }
            }
        }
        keys.put(key, dir);
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException
            {
                register(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    WatchDir(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
        this.recursive = recursive;

        if (recursive) {
            System.out.format("Scanning %s ...\n", dir);
            registerAll(dir);
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } else {
            register(dir);
        }

        // enable trace after initial registration
        this.trace = true;
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        System.out.println("process event");
        boolean processing = false;
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("loop");
            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                processing = false;
                System.out.println("about to take");
                key = watcher.take();
                processing = true;

            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                System.out.println("take interrupted");
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {

                System.out.println("poll");
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    System.out.println("Overflow");
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                // print out event
                System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (recursive && (kind == ENTRY_CREATE)) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            registerAll(child);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // ignore to keep sample readable
                        System.out.println("ex: " + x.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);
                System.out.println("finished this set of files");
                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (processing) {
                System.out.println("processing files...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not processing files");
            }
            System.out.println("End of loop\n\n");
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // parse arguments
        if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2)
            usage();
        boolean recursive = false;
        int dirArg = 0;
        if (args[0].equals("-r")) {
            if (args.length < 2)
                usage();
            recursive = true;
            dirArg++;
        }

        // register directory and process its events
        Path dir = Paths.get(args[dirArg]);
        new WatchDir(dir, recursive).processEvents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could not do that. According to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html), The `WatchService` only provided these events:

> ````
> static WatchEvent.Kind<Path>  ENTRY_DELETE Directory entry deleted.
> static WatchEvent.Kind<Path>  ENTRY_MODIFY Directory entry modified.
> static WatchEvent.Kind<Object>    OVERFLOW A special event to indicate that events may have been lost or discarded. ```
> ````

So you won't know whether there are new files to be create/copy to your directory.

Maybe there are some workarounds you could consider:

- Set a timeout, for that time, if no new file is created, consider the file transfer is finished and start to do the work.
- Let your application to handle the copy, so it could know the progress and trigger work after all file is copied.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @TKJohn. I can tell when a single file has finished uploading but the problem with that is the media I am working with is typically made up of multiple files, for example, there may be a sidecar file that contains the metadata associated with the media file.  So I can't work on single files.  Regarding your second suggestion, the copy can occur via 3 other applications and so I cannot take control of the copy process.

Comment: I'd personally go for timeout approach (because if it's a desktop app, it's a right pain for the user to go through your app for things as simple as copying a file, unless your app is a file manager). @karen, you don't have to work for single files. General idea is to have a counter in your app that ticks up, say, each second, and listens to `ENTRY_CREATE` and `ENTRY_MODIFY` events - and if neither happened for a while, to consider that copying's finished, and you can start processing. How much is "a while" you'll need to see for yourself, as that depends on file size, I think.